# How do you get the bag of hops into the carboy and then remove it?

Tags: hops, dry-hop, techniques

I always have a difficult time getting the hops in the carboy and then removing it when dry-hopping. What's the trick?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easy answer is don't use a bag.  I usually use whole flowers when dryhopping.  They float on top and then I rack to another carboy when done w/ the dryhop.

I used a bag 2x and it was a royal pain in the butt.  Getting it out was always the hard part, brute force was my method.  It always made me worry about contamination.

Comment: Agreed. When I dry-hopped with a bag the leaves absorbed so much wort that I had to wait until they were dry to remove the bag. Some narrow tongs would help you make the bag in to a carboy-hole-shape.

Answer (score 2):

It's easier using pellet hops in the bag. What I do is place the hops in the bag along with a weight of some sort (a stainless butter knife or something thin) to get the bag to sink. Tie a length of dental floss to the top of the bag and lower the bag into the carboy keeping a length of the floss outside the carboy. Lower bag halfway down and then push the stopper/airlock back into the top of the carboy cinching the dental floss in place so that you can pull the bag back up later. I would recommend racking the beer out of the carboy before trying to retrieve the bag because it will expand and need to be worked out of the carboy opening.
mark
www.backyardbrewer.blogspot.com
www.thebackyardbrewer.com

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mark, I've wrestled with this for awhile.  Funny, 20 years brewing in a vacuum... the simple concept of a weight and dental floss never occurred to me... I suppose that says something about my intellect....  I think I love this website.  No more loose pellets in my secondary carboy.